# Take the values from three column based on priority in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, data-wrangling

I have a dataset as below, basically I want a final column (labelled output) which takes value if present in C column if not then in B then in A, I think it can be done with ifelse but I am looking for a tidy solution. If not then ifelse would also work.

[image: Sample dataset]

```
structure(list(a = c(1L, 2L, 12L, NA, NA), b = c(3L, 2L, NA, 
NA, 4L), c = c(NA, 5L, NA, 6L, 2L), Output = c(3L, 5L, 12L, 6L, 
2L)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `coalesce`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    mutate(Output = coalesce(!!! .[3:1]))
# A tibble: 5 x 4
#      a     b     c Output
#  <int> <int> <int>  <int>
#1     1     3    NA      3
#2     2     2     5      5
#3    12    NA    NA     12
#4    NA    NA     6      6
#5    NA     4     2      2
```

---

```
df1 %>%
     mutate(Output = coalesce(c, b, a))
```

Or using `case_when`

```
df1 %>% 
      mutate(Output = case_when(!is.na(c)~ c, !is.na(b) ~ b, TRUE ~ a))
```

---

In `base R`, we can also do

```
as.data.frame(df1[1:3])[cbind(seq_len(nrow(df1)), 
              max.col(!is.na(df1[1:3]), 'last'))]
#[1]  3  5 12  6  2
```